# AngularJs Filter to single array element and output a property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

Im trying to access the property of an array of objects by the current id in a loop.

```
<tr ng-repeat="feature in element.features">
    <td>{{ available_features | filter:{id: feature.feature_id} }}</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>

Available_features:
{
    id: 1
    name: "Feature 1"
},
{
    id: 2
    name: "Feature 2"
},
{
    id: 3
    name: "Feature 3"
},
```

element.features is an array of ids, the id references the id in the available_features array.
This outputs the object but I want the .name property.

**UPDATE:**
Seems It works by:

```
<td>{{ (available_features | filter:{id: feature.feature_id})[0].name }}</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option:

```
<td>{{ (available_features | filter:{id: feature.feature_id})[0].name }}</td>
```

Another option is to change the `available_features` array to an object and use the `id` as *key*, so that you could do something like this:

```
<td>{{ available_features[feature.feature_id].name }}</td>
```

Comment: Just after I updated my question with this solution, yours was here :P Yeah I came to the first option.